# Do Quick Replies Work in Messenger Bot Welcome Message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Do quick replies work in Facebook Messenger Bot Welcome Message? This is the message that is displayed after you press the "Get Started" button.

It might not be supported, but if it is, am I doing something wrong?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
        "message": {
          "attachment": {
            "type": "template",
            "payload": {
              "template_type": "generic",
              "elements": [{
                "title": "Hi dad",
                "subtitle": "Hi mom",
                "item_url": "www.google.com",
                "image_url": "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png",
              }]
            }
          }
        },
        "quick_replies":[
            {
                "content_type":"text",
                "title":"option1",
                "payload":"option1payload"
            },
            {
                "content_type":"text",
                "title":"option2",
                "payload":"option2payload"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/13333333337/thread_settings?access_token=THISISMYCOOLTOKEN"
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Invalid Keys \"message, quick_replies\" were found in param \"call_to_actions[0]\"."type":"OAuthException","code":100
```

Comment: Send them as separate messages right after each other? Should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. `payload` is only for **string** text. see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

- `call_to_actions` is limited to 1 `call_to_actions` must contain at least
  **one `payload` string**.
- This data will be sent back to you via webhook.